# Place one image on top of the other

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

I need to place my second picture (img id="stack") on top of my first picture. I've tried using relative and absolute positioning but it just seems to be below each other.

This is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGND7/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="imgpos">
  <img id="bkgr" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons   /f/fd/Moon_in_Sunrise_Sky_2.jpg" width="400" height="400"> 
  <img id= "stack" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Appearance_of_sky_for_weather_forecast%2C_Dhaka%2C_Bangladesh.JPG" width="200" height="150">       
</div>
```

CSS

```
#imgpos
{
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
 }

 #imgpos bkgr
 {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
 }

 #imgpos stack
 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the octothorpe.

```css
#imgpos #bkgr
{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
}

#imgpos #stack
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Since IDs are unique anyways, you can omit the `#imgpos`, too:

```css
#bkgr {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
}

#stack {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

And since the images are in the right order anyways, you can omit the z-index, too:

```css
#bkgr {
   position: absolute;
}

#stack {
    position: absolute;
}
```

And since the rules are now the same, you can combine them:

```css
#bkgr, #stack {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: TIL octothorpe == poundsign

Comment: Thank you @minitech. It works marvelously now.